# Memory mapped device access in C / Embedded Linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a pxa270 processor kit running embedded Linux that has memory-mapped devices.

How can I store a value in those devices' external memory (if I know their physical address)?

Comment: what you mean by external memory.. could you write longer questions?

Comment: For example: `*(int*)(external_memory) = 42;` or `memcpy(external_memory, "foobar", 6);`

Comment: I've expanded the question per the comments added by the OP.  please reopen.

Comment: FYI, memory-mapped devices are a certain way of controlling hardware, by giving their control registers addresses in physical address space. So this question is actually about how to map that physical address space to your processes's virtual address space, so you can write to it.

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged this "embedded-linux", I'm going to assume that what you want to do is write to the memory of a *memory mapped device*.

There are a few approaches I can think of, but I'm not sure whether the first is possible in Linux:

1. Use system calls to map the device's *physical* memory space into the *virtual* memory space of a running process
2. Write to the virtual file `/dev/mem`
3. Create a *block device driver* which handles your device's memory, and then perform (file) operations against its entry in `/dev`.

(Actually #1 and #2 together might work, using `mmap()` against `/dev/mem` so that you can use normal *memory* read and write ops instead of *file* operations).

Comment: ok,In my question,external memory(is in pxa270 processor kit) suppose say 0x40a00080 that address.Now how are you performing RD/WR operation

Comment: some possible help at http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/fake.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare a pointer of the type you require and assign the memory location to it. Then set your values as normal.

```
int *pointer_to_memory = (int *)address_of_external_memory;
*pointer_to_memory = value;
```

Comment: which will of course only write to that address _relative to the current process's memory space_

Comment: That is a good point. The above is ok for embedded devices where you typically access the entire memory space. I guess mmap would be more useful on a multi-process operating environment.

Comment: ok but how compiler know this memory belongs to external

Comment: the compiler has no idea, it's the O/S that maps addresses from virtual space to physical space.